# Meaning of "to have no patience for..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, nouns

> He has no patience for the view that instead of raising interest rates his next move will be to cut the trendsetting overnight rate.

I'm not a native English speaker. I read the above sentence in a paper and understood all the words. But I am confused about his standpoint. Does "he has no patience for the view" mean:

1. He doesn't like people's view about such? (meaning he doesn't support the idea)
2. He can't wait to say *his* view about such? (meaning he supports the idea)

Comment: I've *never* heard this variant before; it's always *no patience with*.  But neither is more logical than the other, I suppose.

Answer (score 4):

It means he doesn't support the idea - he has quite possibly heard it many times before so knows the viewpoint but doesn't want to hear it again.